# CKeditor PHP file for it instead for asp

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded CKeditor and when i unzipped the files, there is a file named CKeditor.asp.
i tried to find the php version for it but couldn't.
can any one help me?

and are there any other better options for rich text editors, i want to use it for my blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard download contains both ASP and PHP and you can simply grab the files you want and bin the rest. There's even different sample files for PHP4 and PHP5 so have a look at them to select which one you want.

As for the folders, I suggest keeping all but the _samples. Although it might be helpful to check them out as well and decide if you want to keep them too, the contains some nice tips and tricks you might need.